# Azure Search Indexer is too slow for large amount of documents

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I have S1 tier with about 600,000 files in the single container in the blob storage. I've restricted the index to include only (.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.ppt,.pptx,.pdf,.txt,.rtf,.htm,.html) and excluding (.png,.jpeg,.jpg,.gif,.psd,.mp3,.mp4,.wav,.exe,.zip,.dmg,.msi,.mkv,.flv,.ogg,.ogv,.avi,.mov,.wmv). I also tried to increase the partitions to the max allowed 12 with no considerable changes in the performance.

With the current indexing speed, I can estimate 30 days to finish the process.

I need this to be indexed quicker. How can I increase the speed of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up indexing by parallelizing it: split blobs in your container into several folders, and create several datasource / indexer pairs all writing into the same target search index. If your search service has N search units, N indexer can be running concurrently, resulting in a significant speed-up of indexing.

Comment: I have a single container and all files are in the root folder. How can I handle with multiple Indexers in this scenario? Also, there are limits in terms of a number of Datasourcers and Indexers in my tier (S1).